# getResources() or create own static class?

Tags: android

I noticed myself constantly typing:

```
someVar = getResources().getString(R.string.someString);
```

I have several XML files that I am parsing and building and in order to make sure that the files stay consistent, I have placed the tag names in the res/values/strings.xml file. The same handles are used throughout several activities, and some of those activities extend ListActivity while others do not so creating a simple super class which houses these variables ( ex:

```
public class thisClass extends thatClass 
{...}

public class thatClass 
{
    package String someTag = "this";
    package String otherTag = "that"; 
}
```

I would assume that all of these calls to getResources() could get pretty taxing and was wondering if it is beneficial to instead create an R-type file where I can store these types of commonly used variables statically ex:

```
public final class globalVars 
{
    public static final class XML_TAGS 
    {
        static final String someTag = "this";
        static final String otherTag = "that";
    }
}
```

and to reference these variables like such:

```
serializer.startTag("", globalVars.XML_TAGS.someTag);
```

instead of

```
serializer.startTag("", getResources().getString(R.string.someTag));
```

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, after looking into the source code of [android.content.res.resources](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/content/res/Resources.java.htm) and some other classes, it is evident that using Resources and getting resources through `getResources()` is **costly *compared to a static class***.

Indeed, the instance of `Resources` returned is not a static container but rather an object that gets resources by executing a couple of statements (whether a string or drawable or any other form).

**However**, **using getResources() has its advantages**:

- It helps you *externalize your resources*.
- For any type of resource, you can specify default and multiple alternative resources depending maybe on *Locale*, *Screen Depth/Resolution*...

A `static` container might provide a less costly alternative than using resources but remember: any later attempt at localization would be relatively extremely costly.