# Whether we should give string values in Strings.xml or in layput xml file itself

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one ques that whether it is good to give all string text that we are going to use in our layout file in strings.xml file or should we give it in "string text" in layout file itself for attribute values like `android:text="some text"`.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/ll1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button android:text="Button" 
    android:id="@+id/butShow" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Button>


</LinearLayout>
```

then is it fine to give `android:text="Button"` or we should use `android:text="@string/btnlabel"`

strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="btnLabel">Button</string>
</resources>
```

We should specify all string text in strings.xml or only specific ones.

Comment: in both ways u can write the code

Answer (score 1):

[check my answer hereOk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937566/getresources-or-create-own-static-class/6938092#6938092)

After looking into the source code of [android.content.res.resources](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/content/res/Resources.java.htm) and some other classes, it is evident that using Resources and **getting resources through `getResources()` is a bit costly**.

**However**, ***using getResources() has its advantages***:

- It helps you *externalize your resources*.

> For any type of resource, you can specify default and multiple alternative resources depending maybe on *Locale*, *Screen Depth/Resolution*...

---

Answer (score 0):

You will do better to extract all your strings to strings.xml incase you ever decide to internationalize your app! then you only have to do a different strings.xml for each language rather than layouts too

Comment: how do you do that!!??